# Why does Zouken need both Illya and Sakura?

Tags: fate-stay-night

During the HF route, Zouken wants to use both Illya and Sakura as Grails. His plan is to summon the Greater Grail to give birth to Avenger. But in Sakura there are the worms of Zouken. When Avenger assimilates Sakura, Zouken will take possession of his body through his worms.

Illya and Sakura are Lesser Grails with the same functions, so why does Zouken need both? In fact, one is enough. After Shirou and Kotomine saved Illya, Zouken proceeded to summon the Greater Grail using only Sakura.

Comment: If you read through the vn, you would know that he wanted to use Sakura as a false vessel for the lesser grail so that he could use to forge a contract with Angra Manyu and then take over (her body) for himself (thus the crestworms) with as an undying body with limitless prana (true immortality)

Comment: I read Novel, I already understood it. It is my fault I think I expressed the question unclearly, now I edit it.